# Spotfire How To Change Calculate Totals Using Iron Python

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I have a Cross Table in my Spotfire Dashboard and am trying to change the "Calculate Totals" option using an Iron Python script.

[image]

I've found [this link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_CrossTableTotals_CalculationMode.htm) on Spotfire API. So, from what I understood, this information is stored in myVis.Totals. But, for whatever the reason, this seems to be a read-only property as can be seen [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/html/P_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_CrossTablePlot_Totals.htm).

Have any of you ever had this problem and would know how to fix it?

This is my code:

```py
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

# myVis is a script parameter of the type "Visualisation"
myVis = myVis.As[Visualization]()
myVis.Totals = CrossTableTotals.CalculationMode.SumOfCellValues
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: can't assign to read-only property Totals of type 'CrossTablePlot'


System.MissingMemberException: can't assign to read-only property Totals of type 'CrossTablePlot'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.IronPython27.IronPythonScriptEngine.ExecuteForDebugging(String scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

myVis.Totals.DefaultCalculationMode=CrossTableTotals.CalculationMode.SumOfCellValues

Gaia

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed, Gaia! Thank you very much!